# Given a node network, how to find the highest scoring loop with finite number of moves?

Tags: algorithm, nodes

For a project of mine, I'm attempting to create a solver that, given a random set of weighted nodes with weighted paths, will find the highest scoring path with a finite number of moves. I've created a visual to help describe the problem.

[image: example]

[image: complete example]

*This example has all the connection edges shown for completeness. The number on edges are traversal costs and numbers inside nodes are scores. A node is only counted when traversed to and cannot traverse to itself from itself.*

As you can see from the description in the image, there is a start/finish node with randomly placed nodes that each have a arbitrary score. Every node is connected to all other nodes and **every connection has an arbitrary weight that subtracts from the total number of move units remaining.** For simplicity, you could assume the weight of a connection is a function of distance. Nodes can be traveled to more than once and their score is applied again. The goal is to find a loop path that has the highest score for the given move limit.

The solver will never be dealing with more than 30 nodes, usually dealing with 10-15 nodes. I still need to try and make it as fast as possible.

Any ideas on algorithms or methods that would help me solve this problem other than pure brute force methods?

Comment: Seems similar to a DP weighted knapsack type problem. Google around for Dynamic Programming and check [this](http://www.programminglogic.com/knapsack-problem-dynamic-programming-algorithm/) out

Comment: "Nodes can be traveled to more than once" Do they score more than once?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes. This is implied as all nodes are connected to all other nodes; there is no point in moving to a node if not to gain its score as nodes are not navigation limits. Updated question.

Comment: Is it correct to say that, if we take some steps, the scoring of the remaining steps does not depend on the exact history? If so, there's a polynomial-time dynamic program. I'll post details in a while if no one else does.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat If I understand you correctly, no it does not. The only limitations are that you start on the start node, end on the start node, and do not exceed the move/step limit. When you move to a node, you must move from that node to another ie your current position matters. Either way, I'm interested to see what you have.

Comment: @drunkenRabbit Thanks for the link, this problem does seem similar to a one-dimensional knapsack problem with perhaps the only difference being that the "weight" of said objects differ based on which node we are currently at whereas the score remains constant. So putting a "weight node" in the "knapsack" changes the weights of all other nodes. Perhaps then my question lacks crucial information as an equation outlining that "change in weight" may be relevant in finding a solution instead of it being just arbitrary changes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an O(m n^2)-time algorithm, where m is the number of moves and n is the number of nodes.

For every time t in {0, 1, ..., m} and every node v, compute the maximum score of a t-step walk that begins at the start node and ends at v as follows. If t = 0, then there's only walk, namely, doing nothing at the start node, so the maximum for (0, v) is 0 if v is the start node and -infinity (i.e., impossible) otherwise.

For t > 0, we use the entries for t - 1 to compute the entries for t. To compute the (t, v) entry, we add the score for v to the difference of the maximum over all nodes w of the (t - 1, w) entry minus the transition penalty from w to v. In other words, an optimal t-step walk to v consists of a step from some node w to v preceded by a (t - 1)-step walk to w, and this (t - 1)-step walk must be optimal because history does not influence future scoring.

At the end, we look at the (m, start node) entry. To recover the actual walk involves working backward and determining repeatedly which w was the best node to have come from.

Comment: In all honesty I don't understand where you're coming from with this; you may have misunderstood the question. I really don't know what you mean by "history doesn't matter". The nodes must be traversed, meaning you move from one node to the next. Doing this means you are altering the travel times to all nodes with each move since your position is changing and every node has their own unique set of connections to every other node whose connection weights differ from the previous node.

Comment: @Slight I mean proper history doesn't matter; only where you are now matters.

Comment: Right well, either way your answer doesn't seem to contain a solution but more of an idea and even then it seems vague. You realize each node transition is variable in cost and the whole "working backwards" part sounds like were the solution should go. If you really have a solution here, I'd definitely like to hear it should you care to elaborate.